# Angular TypeError: Cannot create property 'x' on string '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({

})

export class LocalStorageService {
    private store;

    constructor() {
        this.store = {}
        console.log("constructor", this.store)
    }

    getItem(key: string) {
        console.log("get", this.store)
        return this.store[key];
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        console.log("set", this.store)
        this.store[key] = value;
    }
}
```

I run this test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // omit
    storage = TestBed.get(LocalStorageService);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(storage.getItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake(storage.setItem);
});

it('should store local status', () => {
    localStorage.setItem("x", "y");
});
```

When the test is executed i get 2 logs:

`LOG: 'constructor', Object{}`

`LOG: 'set', '[object Object]'`

Something seems to cast the `store` property from object to string, this is the error i get: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'x' on string '[object Object]'`

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the object is passing empty, and localstorage don`t store objects...

Press F12 > go to console > do localStorage.setItem("x", {name: 'renato'}) and then try to get the value > localStorage.getItem("x")

the result is gonna be "[object Object]"